# How to import an R6 class into a package?

Tags: r, r6

I would like to use functions in my personal package built on top of an R6 class called `ms_team` defined inside of the `Microsoft365R` package. Right now these functions all fail because even though I import the functions I need, when I try to call one of my functions which rely on them, I get an error that this object is not found.

> Error in login$get_team(team_id) : object 'ms_team' not found

I have tried to include `@importFrom Microsoft365R ms_team ...` in my function, but with no success. What are the magic words to use functions which rely on externally defined R6 classes in a package?

Comment: Including `library(Microsoft365R)` in the procedure let's the function find it. Is there a better way?

Comment: Make sure you have `#' @importFrom...` as the directive, and not, say `# @importFrom...` without the '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft365R dev here. I assume you're using roxygen2.

To import an exported object (any object, not just an R6 class) from another package, put

```
#' @importFrom pkgname objname
NULL
```

in one of your package's R files. In this case, you would do

```r
#' @importFrom Microsoft365R ms_team
NULL
```

It may be easier, and more robust, to import the entire package though:

```r
#' @import Microsoft365R
NULL
```

See [here](https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R/blob/master/R/Microsoft365R.R#L1-L2) for how I import the AzureGraph package into Microsoft365R itself, for example.

Answer (score 0):

As of version [`2.3.1`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/news/news.html) (September 2021) it is possible to use `Microsoft365R` without the package being on the search list.

This means that you don't have to import the whole package anymore. You can now add `Microsoft365R` to `Imports` in your `DESCRIPTION` file, and call functions/objects like `Microsoft365R::function()` / `Microsoft365R::object`.